# Is there an online tool for creating a Tesseract 3 trained data file?

Tags: tesseract

I have read through tutorials on tesseract training on Google's website and multiple other sites.  I'm using the iOS build of Tesseract so I don't think I have the normal command line tools required to train a data set.

I've created a .tif file and the corresponding .box file using http://pp19dd.com/tesseract-ocr-chopper/

The documentation says "That is all there is to it!" which is extremely misleading as there are a whole lot of steps and it seems like many of them could be automated or at least presented using some simple web-based tool.

Is there any online tool that I can upload the .tif and .box and have it generate the .traineddata file?  I'd be willing to host this tool if someone can help me develop it.